# JMeter - injecting variables into a HTTP Request

Tags: apache, jmeter

I'm trying to work with JMeter to test some web services. So far so good, but I was wondering if you could do the following -

I make a http POST request to create a resource, and if successful the response comes back with the location of the resource in the headers. What I would like to do is take the value of this header, and use it in a http GET request to retrieve the resource. Is this possible with JMeter?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to extract the header value to a variable by using a regex. Then use the variable like any other variable in your GET request.

Comment: I've tried that - but I'm unsure of how to set the URL using the parameter - at the minute my reg exp extractor is set to "Apply to: JMeter Variable 'ID'" and in the next http request my url is formatted '/api/${ID}" but it isn't working

Comment: If the GET request contains the unresolved variable, it's often because the regex didn't match anything (set the "Default value"-field to something like NO_ID to check). I would check the regex extractor: is the "Headers" checkbox checked? Can you double-click the POST response, and test the regular expression against the actual received headers?

Comment: I can view the post response in the "View Results Tree" and see the header there, but I can't run any reg exp against it (from the Samepler result tab)

Comment: Found out what was wrong - in the reg exp extractor I had selected JMeter Variable which I thought meant apply it to the variable, selected main and Sub Samples and it works :)

Comment: Great! Also, adding a "view results tree" should give you a chance to test test regex against responses. It is useful for debugging, but it should not be used in actual load tests.